# Drilling down into data using specific Pivot header

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a specific header (in this case "trades") to drill down into the data. I tried using the recorder but it used a cell reference (which is likely to change depending on contents of pivot). I have looked at other sources and I tried the following code:

```
Sub test() 
    Dim pvt AS PivotTables
    Sheets("worksheetname").Activate
    pvt("nameofpivottable").PivotFields("Trades").Select
    Selection.ShowDetail = True
End Sub
```

Once running this code, I am getting the object variable or with block variable not set.

Comment: The problem with your existing code is that `pvt` is never `Set`.

Comment: Thanks, so I need to add a ```Set pvt = PivotTables("Equity Pivot 1") ```?

Comment: `Dim pvt as PivotTable`, `Set pvt = Sheets("WorksheetName).PivotTables("nameofpivottable")`.

Comment: Thanks, do I need to also ```SET``` PivotFields?

Comment: Not with your current approach, because you don't have a variable for it.

Comment: Here is the code I am now using but I am still not getting the same result as if I was double clicking on the pivotfield name. ```Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Set pvt = Sheets("sheetname").PivotTables("pivotname")
    Sheets("sheetname").Activate
    PivotTables("pivotname").PivotFields("fieldname").Select
    Selection.ShowDetail = True```

Comment: you try to show detail on a pivot table field name. ShowDetail will be on an aggregated or grouped value. For this, you need to select a row on the body of the pivot table. If you have a single aggregated value that's fine, else you will need a loop to open the details for each values

Comment: you can try:pvt.PivotFields("fieldname").PivotItems("itemname").DataRange.Select or Intersect(pt.PivotFields("fieldname").Pivotitems("itemname").DataRange.EntireRow, pt.PivotFields("fieldname").DataRange).Select and then selection.showdetail = true

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get that to work. I've been playing around with another method and am very close. Will report back when solved.